# How to remove duplicate phrases in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, replace

Suppose I have a string such as

```
'I hate *some* kinds of duplicate. This string has a duplicate phrase, duplicate phrase.'
```

I want to remove the second occurrence of `duplicate phrase` without removing other occurrences of its constituent parts, such as the other use of `duplicate`.

Moreover, I need to remove **all** *potential* duplicate phrases, not just the duplicates of some specific phrase that I know in advance.

I have found several posts on similar problems, but none that have helped me solve my particular issue:

- [Removing duplicate *words*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794208/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-words-in-a-string-with-python)
- [Removing duplicate *lines*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518340/remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-string-in-python)
- [Removing repeated words *within a phrase*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065164/is-there-a-way-to-remove-duplicate-and-continuous-words-phrases-in-a-string)

I had hoped to adapt the approach from the last link there (`re.sub(r'\b(.+)(\s+\1\b)+', r'\1', s)`) for my purposes, but could not figure out how to do so.

**How do I remove all arbitrary duplicate phrases of two or more words from a string in Python?**

Comment: Does the size of these phrases is arbitrary? Can they appear anywhere on the text?

Comment: For example this `'aaa ccc bbb aaa ccc'` Has the duplicate phrase `"aaa ccc"` but to find that out you would have to iterate over all phrases in the string. Maybe a suffix tree can help to go faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your attempts and comments. I have finally found a solution:

```
s = 'I hate *some* kinds of duplicate. This string has a duplicate phrase, duplicate phrase.'
re.sub(r'((\b\w+\b.{1,2}\w+\b)+).+\1', r'\1', s, flags = re.I)
# 'I hate *some* kinds of duplicate. This string has a duplicate phrase.'
```

#### Explanation

The regular expression

```
r'((\b\w+\b.{1,2}\w+\b)+).+\1'
```

finds every occurrence of multiple runs of alphanumeric characters separated by one or two [any character] (to cover the case where words are separated not just by a space, but perhaps a period or comma and a space), and then repeated following some run of [any character] of indeterminate length. Then

```
re.sub(r'((\b\w+\b.{1,2}\w+\b)+).+\1', r'\1', s, flags = re.I)
```

replaces such occurrences with the first multiple run of alphanumeric characters separated by one or two [any character], being sure to ignore case (since the duplicate phrase could sometimes occur at the beginning of a sentence).

Comment: So does this regex only works on the second sentence?

Comment: I'm asking, because it did not work for this:   s = 'I hate *some* kinds of duplicate, duplicate. This string has a duplicate phrase, duplicate phrase.'

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex Your comment uncovered an inaccurate statement I made in response to a comment on the question. I'm specifically looking at phrases of 2+ words, so I did not mean it to cover such a case. I will edit the question & answer later to make this clear for future viewers.